# Code to Generate a Sequential Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform whose image is below.

[image]

What i need is when i open the userform, there should be sequential number against voucher # textbox.

for example.
Column B has values BPV/1, BPV/2, BPV/3.
What i need is when i run the userform, the voucher # textbox should show the next serial number i.e. BPV/4 and so on...

Below is my code.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim NextNum As Long, prefix As String
Dim i As Long

prefix = "BPV/"
NextNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(2))
i = NextNum + 1

Me.TextBox2.Enabled = False
Me.TextBox2.Value = prefix & i

End Sub
```

Kindly review the code and advise how to achieve it.

Thanks
Salman Khan

Comment: Will the string always be "BPV/" and have the number at the end with nothing else?

Comment: How is your code not working?

Comment: string will remain the same.

Comment: the code is not generating the next serial number

Comment: Will the last row always have the highest number?

Comment: Are you entering `BPV/#` into column B as you create them or are they already there?

Comment: The last will always have the highest number

Comment: No i have to create

Comment: @Salman Khan try the code in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find the `Max` value in Column B , that consists of `String`s, I am reading the strings into an array on type `Long` (in case you have very large numbers), using the `Mid` function. Afterwards, I can find the `Max` value in the array of numbers.

Conveting using the `Mid` function is done with the following line:

```
myArr(lRow) = CLng(Mid(.Cells(lRow, 2), 5))
```

the value 5 is calculated by `Len(prefix) +1`

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim NextNum As Long, prefix As String
Dim LastRow As Long, lRow As Long
Dim myArr() As Long

prefix = "BPV/"

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    'find last row with data in Column B
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    ReDim myArr(2 To LastRow)
    ' read all cells contents and convert them to array of numbers
    ' start from 2nd row , 1st row has headers
    For lRow = 2 To LastRow
        If Mid(.Cells(lRow, 2), 5) <> "" Then
            myArr(lRow) = CLng(Mid(.Cells(lRow, 2), 5))
        End If
    Next lRow

    ' find maximum value in array
    NextNum = WorksheetFunction.Max(myArr)
End With

Me.TextBox2.Enabled = False
Me.TextBox2.Value = prefix & NextNum + 1

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Shai, it gives an error if i place a heading in column B i.e. Voucher #. KIndly advise how to fix.

Comment: @SalmanKhan try edited code, start the `For` loop from row 2 instead of 1

Comment: ReDim myArr(2 To LastRow)

Comment: @SalmanKhan I just ran the code above, worked nicely, Can you upload a screen-shot of "sheet1" to your post ? maybe I am missing something

Comment: I meant a screen shot of Sheet1 with the data,  not the user form

Comment: @ Shai It doesn't gives an error when there is data in row 2. It only gives error when there is no data in row 2...

Comment: @ Shai i resolved the issue by editing the following lines       ReDim myArr(1 To LastRow)
    ' read all cells contents and convert them to array of numbers
    For lRow = 2 To LastRow

Answer (score 0):

You could enter this `FormulaArray` in `Sheet1` let's say in `A1`:

```
=MAX(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B:B,"BPV/","")))
```

Then have this line pointing to that cell:

```
NextNum = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value2
```

- FormulaArrays are entered pressing* `[Ctrl]` *+* `[Shift]` *+* `[Enter]` *simultaneously, you shall see* `{` *and* `}` *around the formula if entered correctly*

Answer (score 0):

This solutions uses the [Application.Evaluate Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx) to obtain the Last Voucher number at once avoiding the use of `For...Next`. It also uses constants *(`Const`)* to hold the Prefix and the `MAX` formula.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize_EEM_Publish()
Const kPrefix As String = "BPV/"
Const kFml As String = "=MAX(IFERROR(1" & _
    "*VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(#rTrg,""#Prefix"",""""))" & _
    "*(SEARCH(""#Prefix"",#rTrg)),0))"
Dim rTrg As Range, sFml As String
Dim lNextNum As Long, l As Long

    Rem Get Last Voucher Number
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("B")
        Set rTrg = .Cells(1).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    sFml = kFml
    sFml = Replace(sFml, "#Prefix", kPrefix)
    sFml = Replace(sFml, "#rTrg", rTrg.Address(, , , 1))
    lNextNum = Application.Evaluate(sFml)

    Rem Set Next Voucher Number
    l = 1 + lNextNum
    Me.TextBox2.Enabled = False
    Me.TextBox2.Value = sPrefix & i

End Sub
```